# How to use Bootstrap datetime picker with jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in datatable. Here I had develop code with showing date with calendar view by using Jquery datepicker but here I need to display the time widget with the calendar view in datatable by using Jedit table library.

I am able to display column with date value if I click on any row in that column the date picker widget gets open can you please tell me how to display time widget with calendar widget.

Thanks in adv..

Following Is the code:

.makeEditable({                                                                                              "aoColumns": [null,null,                                                                                                      {placeholder : ' ',indicator: 'Saving...',                                                                                                    type:"datetimepicker",                                                                                                     tooltip: 'Click to change ticket due date',onblur: 'cancel',submit: 'Ok',                                                                                                    oUpdateParameters: {                                                                                                            ticket_id: function (){                                                                                                                   return ticketID; }

```js
 <script src="<?=base_url()?>public/admin/js/jquery.dataTables.editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<?=base_url()?>public/admin/js/jquery.datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```html
.makeEditable({
                                                                                               "aoColumns": [null,null,
                                                                                                       {placeholder : ' ',indicator: 'Saving...',
                                                                                                       type:"datetimepicker",
                                                                                                       tooltip: 'Click to change ticket due date',onblur: 'cancel',submit: 'Ok',
                                              


 <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/css/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: please write code what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need create datepicker after row add in datatables.

```
       //Add row
       table.row.add(.....).draw();

        //Create you row datepicker
        $('#strtbuydat_'+id).datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            todayBtn: true,
            language: "fr",
            forceParse: false,
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            onRender: function(date) {
                return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
            }
        });
```

This is a example

[jsFiddler datatables with datepicker.](http://jsfiddle.net/aglachant/Fm2z9/)

Comment: thank you,but i also want to use time picker and it must be with jquery datatable and as i said i am able to pick date widget but i am unable to pick time widget

Comment: this code is with jquery datatables and this logic is the same of you description.

generate a jsfiddler with you code, to i can help you.